# Desktop Linux on LG V500 android tablet

Tags: linux, system-installation, android, tablet

I was surfing the net when I found this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqG8ivP0RkQ&feature=youtu.be

And I immediately decided to install a desktop Linux on my old tablet. But I just cannot get more information about it. I own an LG V500 8.3 inch tablet with Android 4.4.2. I can get it to run linux from an emulator, but my goal is to make it boot linux also! I would like to build a cheap travelling laptop which I code use for coding.